# Getting entrance of building?

Tags: overpass-api, overpass-turbo

I can get informations on, for example, a stadium

```
[out:json];
(
  way[leisure=stadium]["name"~"Picot"](48.69241932797025,6.205483675003052,48.69873617918758,6.218605041503906);
);

out body;
>;
out skel qt;
```

But **is there a way to get its entrance too** (osm tag : entrance=main) ?

I think there is something better than the "around" command, but what... ?

Comment: Have you tried "node"?

Comment: It does'nt work because I search the stadium by its name, and the entrance doesn't have a name key.

Comment: Maybe the stadiums entrance has not been uploaded to OSM yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an area query to find entry=main node inside your stadium way. This doesn't work for every way (it depends on specific Area Creation Rules on the Overpass API server), but your example is just fine:

```
way(266223964);out geom;
map_to_area;  
node(area)[entrance=main];
out;
```

Try it in overpass turbo: http://overpass-turbo.eu/s/AuG

map_to_area maps the way id to the respective area id, to be used for the later area query. That's basically a query to return all nodes inside an area.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I need. And if it doesn't work because of the area type, I still can use an already known polygon with node[entrance=main](poly:“..."). I discovered that after searching more info on map_to_area.